# Fullcalendar - how to get date and hour of cells which is not an events

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Fullcalendar - question is : how to get date and hour of cells which is not an events.

We can get the date, time and other values from the events, but I want to get (and insert) the date and time of the cell to specified div element which has been located on current mouse cursor.
[image]

ex. how to display : 2019-06-17 08:30 in specified  or  element

thx in advance

Comment: You need to check what user selected or? If you need that you can use [select function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback). @Ramzes

Comment: you want this to happen when you hover over it, or something? Unfortunately it's not possible (at least not without modifying the internals of fullCalendar anyway). If you look at the HTML which makes up this view you'll hopefully see why - there is no "cell" in reality, it's just a series of different HTML elements overlaid on top of each other to create a visual effect - an illusion of a grid.  It's not possible to say "I'm hovering over the cell for 17th June at 08.30", simply because such a cell does not physically exist in the markup.

Comment: Perhaps you could review the source code and look at the logic which fullCalendar uses internally for its "select" feature (which _does_ seem to know what date and time is being clicked on) and use it to make your own feature where it can identify and display the same information when hovering the mouse. But it seems like a lot of work for a pretty minor UI feature. The user can already see the date and time by looking at the information at the top of the column and the side of the row. You're not adding any new information particularly. It might be a bit helpful, but not a big improvement.